# springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin forkedSpringBootRun uses the output of task inspectClassesForKotlinIC, jar

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, openapi

I have decided to add springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin to my Spring Boot 3 project to generate Open API v3 docs. By the way, when running the task

`./gradlew clean generateOpenApiDocs` 
I see the following output:

```
> Task :app:forkedSpringBootRun FAILED
== Build Time Summary ==
         ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 28% :app:compileKotlin (0:00.039)
▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 42% :app:forkedSpringBootRun (0:00.057)

== BUILD FAILED ==

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' (type 'JavaExecFork').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/rymko/CreativeDock/account/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' uses this output of task ':app:inspectClassesForKotlinIC' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:inspectClassesForKotlinIC' as an input of ':app:forkedSpringBootRun'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:inspectClassesForKotlinIC' from ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:inspectClassesForKotlinIC' from ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/rymko/CreativeDock/account/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' uses this output of task ':app:jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:jar' as an input of ':app:forkedSpringBootRun'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:jar' from ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:jar' from ':app:forkedSpringBootRun' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 622ms
11 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 1 from cache
```

I have tried different changes, but nothing works :(
Maybe somebody can help?

I tried to add dependsOn in my build.gradle.kts file

```
    named("forkedSpringBootRun") {
        setDependsOn(listOf(jar, inspectClassesForKotlinIC))
    }
```

but the output is

```
* What went wrong:
Task with name 'forkedSpringBootRun' not found in project ':app'.
```